# Limiting voting per user django

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have this code that enables you to vote for an article, right now a user can vote unlimited times I want to make it so when people click the button first time it gets the value by one and then decreased by one and so forth.

here's article.html:

```
<button id="vote">vote</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#vote").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault()
          var upvotes = $("#total_votes").html()
          var updatedUpVotes = parseInt(upvotes) + 1
          $("#total_votes").html(updatedUpVotes)
          $.ajax({
            url: 'vote/',
            method: "GET",
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
              console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (error) {
              console.log(error)
            }
          })
        })
      </script>
```

vote function in views.py:

```
def vote(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    article.votes += 1
    article.save()
    return JsonResponse(data = {"vote": "Voted! Thank you for the vote."})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate model to store Vote information attached with user. Otherwise you will not have any idea who voted that article. You can try something like this:

```
# Model

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

# View

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def vote(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    vote, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(article=article, user=request.user)
    if created:
        return JsonResponse(data = {"vote": "Voted! Thank you for the vote."})
    return JsonResponse(data = {"vote": "You already voted for this article."})
```

**FYI:** even though `GET` request will work, but I would recommend using `POST` method, because as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods):

> Requests using GET should only retrieve data.

But clearly this method will change in Database.

Comment: I get this error TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate model that will contain article id and user id. When click on like button check whether data exists for that user and article. If it exists, decrease the vote by 1 else increase its value.